# localization of places for Reverse Geocoding ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, reverse-geocoding, apple-maps

I am using apple map, My app has multiple languages and I want to change the name of the location in the language selected within the app. I am getting detailed information of locality using `CLPlacemark` via `reversegeocoding`.

Here is my code

```
CLPlacemark *placemarker = [placemarks lastObject];
NSString *locality = placemarker.thoroughfare ?: placemarker.subLocality ?: placemarker.locality;
```

but I am unable to get place name in selected language of the app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25284643/4549304 - it is already answered here

Comment: This is not working, I have found and other solution but still I need to kill the app or need to run the app again to make it work is there any other solution for that.

Comment: Great, you can share the other one, and we may try to look around that one.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution to my own problem working fine, Here is my code

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[REAAppSettingsController sharedInstance] languageTag], nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

 [self.geocoding reverseGeocodeLocation:testLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

  CLPlacemark *placemarker = [placemarks lastObject];
  NSString *locality = placemarker.thoroughfare ?: placemarker.subLocality ?: placemarker.locality;

  if (locality)
  {
    completion(locality);
  }
}
```

}];