# fetch the city of user in English only

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, location, swift4

In my project users cant go to the next view unless they are currently in a specific city. So here is how I check the city of a coordinates

```
func fetchCountryAndCity(location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (String, String) -> ()) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    } else if let country = placemarks?.first?.country,
        let city = placemarks?.first?.locality {
            completion(country, city)
        }
    }
}
```

then when users click on get my current locations I take the coordinates and check:

```
fetchCountryAndCity(location: location) { country, city in
                print("country:", country)
                print("city:", city)
                if city == "Riyadh" || city == "الرياض" || city == "리야드" || city == "Riyah"  {
```

the problem is I have to check the name of the city in all the languages because the output of the city name depends on the language of the device ( As I found out during testing)  and it's just not right. Is there any way other than this to check the name of the city in all languages?

Comment: Use locationsation.

Comment: can you give me more details :)

Comment: this post might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144508/reverse-geocoding-to-return-results-only-in-english

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse geocoding to return results only in English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144508/reverse-geocoding-to-return-results-only-in-english)

Comment: possible but I don't see swift code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSLocalizedString` to get name of Riyadh in the user's language. This requires translation you to enter the name Riyadh in a whole bunch of languages. Wikipedia can lend you a hand without the need for professional translator.

Another approach is to obtain a placemark that you know is within the city, then compare that palcemark's city to what the user entered. This way, both city names are in the user's language:

```
var riyadh: (country: String, city: String)?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Riyadh's city hall
    fetchCountryAndCity(location: CLLocation(latitude: 24.686212, longitude: 46.712462)) { country, city in
        self.riyadh = (country, city)
    }
}
```

When you check the placemark obtained from user's inputs:

```
fetchCountryAndCity(location: CLLocation(latitude: 24.647212, longitude: 46.710844)) { country, city in
    if let riyadh = self.riyadh, riyadh == (country, city) {
        print("Hey it's Riyadh. Name in user locale is \(city)")
    }
}
```

The annoyance of this approach is `riyadh` may not be initialized if you need it very early on in the view controller's lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd rather pick the first approach with `NSLocalizedString` But I need help with that. Do you know any resources?