# how get city name in specific language from google iOS swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, location

how to get location details in arabic language
I tried this code ,  but I always get it in English .

```
func fetchCountryAndCity(location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (String, String, String) -> ())
{

    //let gg : GMSGeocoder = GMSGeocoder()


    let geo : CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geo.accessibilityLanguage = "ar"


    geo.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else if let country = placemarks?.first?.country,
            let city = placemarks?.first?.locality , let SubAdminArea = placemarks?.first?.subLocality {
            completion(country, city , SubAdminArea)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse geocoding to return results only in English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144508/reverse-geocoding-to-return-results-only-in-english)

Answer (score 1):

**Starting in iOS 11**, you can pass a locale to the `reverseGeocodeLocation` request. This will return all results in Saudi Arabian Arabic:

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "ar_sa")

CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, preferredLocale: locale) { placemarks, error in
    // ...
}
```

---

**For iOS < 11**, you have to temporarily changes your app's preferred language to Arabic:

```
// Switch your app's preferred language to Arabic
UserDefaults.standard.set(["ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")

CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
    // Remove the language override
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "AppleLanguages")

    // ...
}
```

(Pardon my ignorance as I do not know how to read Arabic so I don't know if the result is correct)

Comment: I no longer have a Swift 3 compiler but it shouldn't differ too much from Swift 4

Comment: Useful answer. Thank you.