# CLPlacemark localisation issue when comparing strings

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring, clplacemark

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359152/clplacemark-locality-value-changes-if-the-device-language-is-different), but I am not sure that is best one. So I need to compare:

```
if ([placeMark.subAdministrativeArea isEqualToString:@"Los Angeles"] || [placeMark.subAdministrativeArea isEqualToString:@"Orange"])
```

then allow to do some things.

But when I use different to English localisation it's impossible to compare that strings.

Forcing localisation I guess can work, but it's really danger solution as we need just to force it in one place and it will affect on all app settings and can leads to bugs in other places that you even can't expect.